# Angular.js child input element not getting parents scope

Tags: angularjs

This should be pretty simple, but for some reason when I have

```
<div class="file-navigator" ng-controller="FileSystemCtrl">
        <input type="file" id="openFile" ng-model="path" ng-change="openFolder()" nwdirectory />
```

The `ng-change` doesn't get triggered. 
If I use

```
onchange="angular.element(this).parent().scope().openFolder()"
```

the onchange event gets triggered, but obviously, that's ugly.

The FileSystemCtrl is defined as a module which I'm importing into my app, it's structured like this.

```
angular.module('myApp.FileSystemModule',[])
.factory('FileSystemModel',function($rootscope){...})
.controller('FileSystemCtrl',function(){...});
```

Any ideas why the child doesn't know about it's parent controller? Particularly as the child doesn't have a controller of it's own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs doesn't support input with type file. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375). And [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5503). Your onchange event is the best option for now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use a `directive` taking advantage of `$compile` to interact with a `ng-model`:

```
.directive('path', function($compile) { 
    return {
        restrict: 'E',//<path></path> in your markup
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="file" />',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var textField = $(elem).attr('ng-model', 'something');

                $compile(textField)(scope);

                $(elem).change(function() { 
                      //do stuff 
                });

        }
    };
});
```

I didn't test it, but it provides you with a get-go.

Comment: Thanks Roland, I know I have to learn about the compile method for a few other things. I may play with it here.